# Defining a global filter/transformer in Polymer.dart

Tags: dart, dart-webui

Is there a way to define a global transformer that will be available in all custom elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a global way to define a transformer, but I use the following workaround:
I have a class containing my global transformers, that are included into my custom elements using a mixin. Put it into a library that you include into every element. My global transformer mixin:

```dart
abstract class GlobalTransformersMixin extends Object implements Observable {
  @observable
  final Transformer asInteger = new _StringToInt();
  //...
}
```

Using it in an custom element:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-elment')
class MyElement extends PolymerElement with GlobalTransformersMixin {
    //...
}
```