# How can I register a global filter in my dart application

Tags: dart, expression, dart-polymer

I want to register a [filter function](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions) in order to reuse it in my templates when I need it.

It is possible to register it somewhere?

The [polymer expressions package documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/polymer_expressions) explains how to register a filter at top-level. That means that I can use it anywhere or only in the template used for the registration?

I've saw also [old examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936287/how-to-register-a-polymerexpression-filter-inside-a-custom-element-in-polymer-d) but they don't work anymore.

Comment: The code from the package documentation also doesn't work? You should create a bug report then or at least ping the exiting ones. There was an answer on a similar question recently which suggested to use a Mixin but I haven't found it. It is not like a global but at least reusable.

Comment: Do you know if defining a global filter makes it available in all the templates in the application?

Comment: I think I have never tried this. As far as I understand at first it was necessary to register a filter as global but within each component where you wanted to use them. Then support for component methods as filters was added and registering in globals become obsolete. I guess there is no way to register filters one and use everywhere and probably never was (Polymer.dart only).
Therefore the mixin approach seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: Are you referring to this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25910776/555220

Comment: That was it - thanks for the link!.